# Update docker container when new image is getting released

Tags: docker, docker-watchtower

Except watchtower what other tools we have in order to update containers when a new image is getting released?

Watchtower seems good but t does not support yet private registry other than docker hub, ie I would like to use gitlab registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in [watchover issue 3](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower/issues/3), with reference to [PR 13](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower/pull/13) which allows for pulling private images (on Docker Hub though).

You need to apply [PR 26](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/watchtower/pull/26) in order to fix support for private docker registry authentication. This is where the latest effort to support private images is being developed, as there is no other alternative project that I could find.